# Lync 2013 cannot show custom Presence status

Tags: c#, wpf, lync-2013

I am a first step developer of Lync.
I want to development the system that manage the employee job and attendance with the custom presence status.
I can get custom presence status from my project.But this custom presence status cannot show in MS Lync 2013 client except avalibility(busy,online,etc.,).

How can I work to show the activity(custom status) in Lync 2013?

Now I referenced the follow site to configure the Lync 2013 .
http://blog.schertz.name/2010/11/adding-custom-presence-to-lync/

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have followed all the steps mentioned in the blog, simply restart your machine for the HTTPS change to take place. That should solve your problem.